# JavaScript working in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have a simple test page which seems to be working in Chrome but Not in Firefox.

The `HTML` Code is:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test Title</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <script scr="test.js"> </script>

      <h1> Test </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

The `JavaScript` code is:

```
alert("Hello World");
alert("Hello World");  
alert("Hello World");
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There is no difference between firefox and chrome when it comes to the alert functionality. Maybe chrome blocks multiple popups? Whats the result you are seeing? Absolutely nothing in Firefox?

Comment: 1) which version?
2) In which one dosen't work?

Comment: script scr ==> script src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your script elements source property got a typo and I would always use the MIME-Type info. try:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>`

Furthermore, script definitions aswell as css links etc. should normaly be placed in the `<head>` section of your html document, not in the `<body>`

**EDIT:**

Actually the script MIME-Type is kinda deprecated and is not needed anymore. However, it does no harm if left in there.